# Table data deleted without warning KQL/Kusto/Data Explorer

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, kusto-explorer

Two of my tables suddenly had all data within them deleted.  These tables where created over a year ago.  Both tables have not changed in any way over the last year.  These tables are queried daily by a power automate flow.  Looking at the recent commands that have been run on the database I see a bunch of drop extent commands that are run automatically (not sure if this is the cause).

Questions:

- How can I determine the reason that the data in both these tables was deleted?
- How can I recover the data that was deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I determine the reason that the data in both these tables was deleted?

If you have database-admin / database-monitor privileges, you can look at the [Journal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/journal) and look for operations that dropped extents (data shards) from the table.

> Looking at the recent commands that have been run on the database I see a bunch of drop extent commands that are run automatically (not sure if this is the cause).

This likely indicates that there's a [retention policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/retentionpolicy) with a non-infinite soft delete period configured on this database/table. if you wish for data to be retain beyond this period, you'll need to alter the retention policy.

> How can I recover the data that was deleted?

If the table had `recoverability` set to `enabled` in its effective retention policy, and less than 14 days have passed since the data was dropped - you can open a support ticket for requesting to recover the data.

Comment: thanks @Yoni,  They were both stagnant data tables so I was able to reload the data without initiating a recovery.  How can I check the retention policy and update so this doesn't happen in the future?  Ideally, I want these tables to remain forever.

Comment: > "How can I check the retention policy and update so this doesn't happen in the future?" use the appropriate ".show" commands for table/database policies. see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/show-table-retention-policy-command and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/show-database-retention-policy-command